# Why the player Setting in my Unity for android platform does not display?

Tags: android, unity3d

I changed the platform of my Unity project to android, then click the Player Settings button in order to change the company name and package name. [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kO2P4.png)

[But then Unity does not show anything in the player setting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDw1S.png)
My unity version is 2019.3.0a3. [In the console, it shows some errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axyWp.png)

Please help me to fix this problem, thanks.

Comment: Does this issue persist after a restart? Also, had you considered to switch to a non-alpha version of Unity?